# Structure of character varieties

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

In a seminal work [The Symplectic Nature of Fundamental Groups of Surfaces](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ewmg/SymplecticNature.pdf), Goldman studied the space $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$ of homomorphisms from a surface group $\Gamma$ (the fundamental group of a closed surface) to a Lie group $G$. He showed that under very general conditions on $G$ (mainly, $G$ to be reductive) the quotient $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$ (under the $G$-action by conjugation) is a nice symplectic space by means of group cohomology, cup product and Poincaré duality.

> How to study $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$ and its connected components when $G$ is not reductive ?

Thanks for any hints!